# Using an array to manipulate Class members

Tags: android, class

Newbee here.
In an Android app I have a class ProdMod.
I can assess the class programmatically by pm = new ProdMod();

There are many members of the class t1, t2, t3, …  t35.
Programmatically I can manipulate a member by pm.t1 = value

What I would like to do is to be able to specify which member I want to access, such as  pm.t4  or pm.t23 programmatically in response to a parameter (PARAM).
In other words when PARAM =13    I want pm.t13=value;
when PARAM = 30 I want pm.t30=value.

I can accomplish this via a switch using the values of PARAM as the cases.

My question is:  is there a way to accomplish this with less code?  Is there a way to change the value of xxx  in pm.xxx such that when PARAM is 7  pm.xxx will be recognized by Android as pm.t7  and when PARAM is 21 pm.xxx will be recognized by Android as pm.t21

Thanks in advance for your help.  Sample code is appreciated.
Jim

Comment: Use an array instead of individual members!

Comment: I'll be blunt:  this is unreadable

Comment: As a more constructive comment, you need to edit your question so that it's actually legible -- one giant run-own paragraph with no code formatting is extremely difficult to read.  Also, use the appropriate tags for your question (I suspect `android`, maybe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array instead of individual fields! Your `PARAM` will be an index of this array.

Before:

```
class ProdMod
{
  public float t1;
  public float t2;
  public float t3;
  public float t4;
  public float t5;

  public ProdMod() { }

  // ...
}
```

After:

```
class ProdMod
{
  private float[] t = new float[5];
  public float get_t_element(int i) { return t[i]; }
  public void set_t_element(int i, float value) { t[i] = value; }

  public ProdMod() { }

  // ...
}
```

Here `t` contains `float`s, and only 5, not 35, but this is just an example. Note that the index argument `i` of `get_t_element` and `set_t_element` in the second example runs from 0 to 4, not from 1 to 5. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is the official Java tutorial on arrays.